# Bootstrap loading bar + button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a download page for my website. I need to it have an animated loading bar and when the loading bar is complete the download button should then appear. I made it in jsfiddle and it all works there but it doesnt seem to work on my website. I am using an updated version of bootstrap on my website but I don't see why that should make a difference.

Summary: The loading bar on my website doesn't actually load

My website: http://coden.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/downloads/download/download_sourcecode/

```
$(".btn-success").hide();
var progress = setInterval(function () {
       var $bar = $('.bar');
      if ($bar.width() >= 400) {
       clearInterval(progress);
       $(".btn-success").show();
       $('.progress').removeClass('active');
   } else {
       $bar.width($bar.width() + 40);
  }
 }, 115);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9NAcb/5/

Comment: you forgot `$(document).ready(function() { your code })`

Comment: And you load Bootstrap.js after your script

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Something with your CSS files. I don't see styles for `.progress-striped .bar`

Comment: I didnt do all the css, the base is made from twitter-bootstrap. If you want info on the progress bars: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress (The animated one is the one im trying to use)

Comment: I know. But you use Bootstrap 2 in your code and Bootstrap 4 CSS. Boostrap 4 has `.progress-bar` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Bootstrap 2 in your code and Bootstrap 4 CSS. Boostrap 4 CSS has `.progress-bar` class.

Comment: Ahh thanks, it all works now. I always seem to make silly mistakes and get stuck for days.